# Goldengate for SQL Server - exact from tables with CLOB/BLOB columns very slow

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, clob, oracle-golden-gate, oracle-cdc

We are running GG for SQL Server on a OCI VM. This is connecting to an on-premisis SQL Server instance. Initial sync and continuous replication works perfectly with most tables. We are running into issues when the tables have LOB columns.

We are experiencing extreme delays. It has been running for **18 hours** and has extracted only **700k rows**. We also have OCI GG working with Oracle source with LOB columns, we have no issues. **1.3M** rows loaded in **20 minutes**.

Network is not an issue as large tables without LOB columns from on-prem SQL Server to trail files on VM in OCI runs pretty quickly.

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong here is highly appreciated.

Comment: If by _LOB_ columns you mean `image`, `ntext` and `text` those have been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) by Microsoft since at least SQL Server 2005. Why are you still using them?

Comment: What does your ODBC configuration look like? Are you using the Named Pipes or TCP/IP client protocol? Named Pipes wraps the already-very-chatty TDS protocol with flow control and performs less than great over high latency connections.

Comment: The source database is of version, Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU18). The table has one column of type TEXT. Unfortunately, the source is an operational system on which we have little to no control. We are building a downstream data platform.  I am trying to see if we can type case the TEXT to a fixed length of some sort, which might possibly reduce memory allocation and inturn network traffic.

Comment: It will only use as much memory and bandwidth as it needs, the problem is round-tripping. Selecting a legacy LOB column in a dataset only returns a 16 byte pointer in each row, you have to make an additional call using that pointer to retrieve the actual LOB data - multiply that by the number of rows in your dataset and you can see why that's slow even on a local connection. Over a WAN connection and embedded inside the Named Pipes protocol... painful.

Comment: The same thing works over ODI without issues. i.e. same table replicated in few minutes. In my previous work, we did this with Informatica and it works like a charm. No difference between a table with / without CLOB. Something about GG extract process that is making it slow. The trial files are massive. Table size is 2.34GB, but the trail file size is 42GB and counting. The max text repl size in SQL Server is 2.14GB. We are thinking that might be a factor. I'm sure there must be a parameter in GG that helps control this basic usecase.